# Jquery script isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have here autocomplete script with not allowing value that not in the option list. But the problem is the script isn't working. When I tried to input, the only comes out in textbox is []. Why my script isn't working properly?

**Script in Mainpage**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete('autocomplete.php?', { mustMatch: true });
});

function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val
    });
}

$('input#autocomplete').result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    //$("#result").html(!data ? "No match found!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).search();
    $(this).css("background-color", "#D6D6FF");
});
</script>
```

**Html in Mainpage**

```
Drop1
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
<select id="main" name="main" onchange="changeAutoComplete(this.value)">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
<input id="autocomplete" />
```

Here's my ajax in **autocomplete.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015") or die("Database Error");
$auto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["term"]);
$selected = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["selected"]);
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM code WHERE item LIKE '%$auto%' AND cat_code='$selected' GROUP BY id ORDER BY item" ); 

if($sql)
{
    $str = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $str[] = $row['item'];
    }
    echo json_encode($str);
}
```

Comment: you are not passing any source to the autocomplete

Comment: @ArunPJohny what should I do with this?

Comment: what is the source of the data that should be displayed in the autocomplete? is it suppose to come via an ajax request

Comment: if it is an ajax request what are the column names returned from the ajax request and the data format

Comment: @ArunPJohny the data that should display in autocomplete is based on value in option list. I have there a dropdown that when I select, the data or records of that value display in autocomplete.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Column name are, item, cat_code only. But I need to display only the item based on it's category code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny How I can fix this? Please